# CDI typesafe resolution is not working in weld 2.2.6 when the the bean type parameter is a type variable

Tags: cdi, wildfly, type-variables

The following code snipset works with "weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar" (the one used by JBoss 7.1.1), but doesn't work with "weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar" (the one used by wildfly 8.2).

```
public class Client<T> {
    public interface Spi<T> {
        T getSomething();
    }

    @Inject
    private Spi<T> spi; // WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Spi<Object>

}

public class SpiImpl implements Client.Spi<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer getSomething() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Why? The CDI 1.2 specification:

> A parameterized bean type is considered assignable to a parameterized
>   required type if they have identical raw type and for each parameter:
>
> 1. the required type parameter and the bean type parameter are actual
>      types with identical raw type, and, if the type is parameterized,
>      the bean type parameter is assignable to the required type parameter
>      according to these rules, or
> 2. the required type parameter is a wildcard, the bean type parameter is an actual type and the actual type is assignable to the upper
>      bound, if any, of the wildcard and assignable from the lower bound, if
>      any, of the wildcard, or
> 3. the required type parameter is a wildcard, the bean type parameter is a type variable and the upper bound of the type variable is
>      assignable to or assignable from the upper bound, if any, of the
>      wildcard and assignable from the lower bound, if any, of the wildcard,
>      or
> 4. the required type parameter is an actual type, the bean type parameter is a type variable and the actual type is assignable to the
>      upper bound, if any, of the type variable, or
> 5. the required type parameter and the bean type parameter are both type variables and the upper bound of the required type parameter is
>      assignable to the upper bound, if any, of the bean type parameter.

So, according to item #4, the above code should work, shouldn't it?

**Edit 1:** <-- *See **Edit 2** before. There I noticed that the CDI implementation is doing what I expected it should do, but I mistakenly thought it didn't.*

Antonin Stefanutti answer is right: item #4 of the mentioned specification don't apply. But, if the actual type of the type variable T is known when the inyectión point is resolved, it is possible to get a proper instance of `Spi`.

Supouse `Client` class is abstract and an implementation specifies the type of the type parameter in the class definition. In that case, the actual type can be discovered and item #4 of the specification would apply.

How can be resolved? By means of introspection, using `Class#getGenericInterfaces()` operation, on the actual `Class` of the `Client` instance. Like this:

```
public class Test {

@Inject
private ClientImpl clientImpl;

public abstract static class Client<T> {
    public interface Spi<T> {
        T getSomething();
    }

    // @Inject inject don't work because CDI doesn't require it even when the actual type of T can be discovered. So, instead, I initialized it programaticaly in the postConstruct()
    private Spi<T> spi; // WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Spi<Object> // Not true, later, in "edit 2" I noteced it works fine. Forget all this. Sorry.

    @Inject
    private Instance<Spi<?>> spiFinder;

    /**Initializes the spi instance variable programaticaly */
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct(){
        ParameterizedType clientType = (ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Type clientTypeParamter = clientType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Class<T> clientParameterClass = (Class<T>)clientTypeParamter;

        final Iterator<Spi<?>> iterator = spiFinder.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Spi<?> spiCandidate = iterator.next();
            ParameterizedType spiCandidateType = (ParameterizedType)spiCandidate.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
            Type spiCandidateTypeParameter = spiCandidateType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            Class<?> spiCandidateParameterClass = (Class<?>)spiCandidateTypeParameter;
            if( clientParameterClass.isAssignableFrom(spiCandidateParameterClass)) {
                if( spi != null)
                    throw new AmbiguousResolutionException();
                spi = (Spi<T>)spiCandidate;
            }
        }
        if( spi == null)
            throw new UnsatisfiedResolutionException();
    }
}

@Dependent
public static class SpiImpl_1 implements Client.Spi<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer getSomething() {
        return 5;
    }
}

@Dependent
public static class SpiImpl_2 implements Client.Spi<Double> {
    @Override
    public Double getSomething() {
        return 5.0;
    }
}

@Dependent
public static class ClientImpl extends Client<Integer> {}

}
```

The above code works (an instance of `SpiImpl_1` is injected into `spi` instance variable), so, why couldn't CDI do this job for us? With instrospection it's possible to discover the actual type of every type parameter declared in the enclosing class/interface definition when the concrete class specifies the actual type of extended superclass's type parameter.

**Edit 2**
Sorry, forget everything I have said. CDI does inject the proper instance of `Client` in this second example without the need of the programatic initialization I added. It doen't throw "WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Spi" where I said it does. I was wrong. Sorry again.
Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the *required type parameter* is a type variable, `T`, and not an actual type so that item #4 does not apply. Actually, any of the conditions mentioned in the specification for assignability of a parameterized bean type to a parameterized required type are met in your example, which implies conclusively that the dependency is not satisfied.

This is somehow related to [CDI-517](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-517), though not identical, yet the clarification can explain the behavioral changes between Weld 1.x and Weld 2.x as the specification has been clarified.

As mentioned in that discussion, having `Spi<Integer>` *assignable* to `Spi<T>` would be incorrect from the Java langage standpoint.